# How do I change the fieldtype of a input field in the magento backend?

Tags: php, magento, custom-backend

I would like to know how I can change the **field type** of a customized input field in the magento backend.

I'm talking about this screen: Customer => Manage Customers => Account Information

Usually there is a .phtml file to configure your fieldtype but for this specific screen i couldn't find any!

In case of the Customer View I was able to find a .phtml file in the following folder: 
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\customer\tab

But as I said, there isn't any for the Account Information screen. Did I miss something?

I'd like to change the type from 'input type="text"' to 'textarea' in the frontend it worked like charm, but in the backend?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You should look into **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab** directory. There are couple of tabs, used on customer edit form. Take a look at **$form->addFieldset** method. The second parameter is the field type, you can change it on your own.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I don't know how to edit the second parameter to get what I want. A field called "notes" in the db should come up as an texarea instead of a input=text. Maybe I'm just to stupit but: help! :)

Comment: The second parameter must be "textarea"